# Erro Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good morning, I'm having a problem when configuring cmake to use the ros Kinetic, I'm following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace, but when running $ catkin_make, I have the problem below:

```
Base path: /home/hiago/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/hiago/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/hiago/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/hiago/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/hiago/catkin_ws/install

####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/hiago/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/hiago/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/hiago/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/hiago/catkin_ws/build"
####

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/hiago/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/hiago/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.5.2") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests

ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/hiago/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:60 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hiago/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/hiago/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I'm not sure about the problem, but I believe it has something to do with the python version since Ros uses one version and CMake another.
I've tried everything, I can't find anything else on the web to help me, help me please!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354106/erro-invoking-%22cmake%22-failed/) by [hiago](https://answers.ros.org/users/55516/hiago/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-05**:\

> Desculpem está mal formatado, minha primeira vez postando uma pergunta

that's not really a problem, we can fix that for you.

What is a problem is that you posted in a language other than English.

This is an English-only forum, so please post your questions in English.

I'll close this for now, but I will re-open after you've translated everything into English.

You don't need to post a new question: just click the `edit` button/link.

**Comment by [hiago](https://answers.ros.org/users/55516/hiago/) on 2020-06-05**:
I've already edited it, I'm so desperate that I didn't pay attention, sorry.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-05**:
No problem. I've re-opened it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-05**:
You write:

> I'm having a problem when configuring cmake to use the ros Kinetic and install ABB

could you link to *what* exactly you are trying to install? We don't know what "install ABB" means.

**Comment by [hiago](https://answers.ros.org/users/55516/hiago/) on 2020-06-05**:
I am trying to configure CMake, this information about "installing ABB" was just information that I thought would be useful, but I will remove them because they are not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would appear to be the classic problem where you're attempting to use a Python interpreter which doesn't have the ROS Python packages installed.

Note this part of the Catkin/CMake output:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
...
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.5.2")
```

ROS Kinetic officially only supports Python 2.x, which means that the official ROS Kinetic Python packages will only be installed for the *system default Python interpreter* on your OS.

Assuming you are running Ubuntu Xenial, this would be Python `2.7.12`.

Assuming you have installed ROS Kinetic using `apt`, the ROS Python packages would have been installed for that version of Python.

I'm not sure *why* CMake decides to use Python 3.x on your system, but that is the problem, as this Python interpreter will not be able to find the `catkin_pkg` package, leading to the error you show.

There *is* a Python 3 version of `catkin_pkg`, but if you have no absolute necessity to use Python 3.x with your Kinetic installation, I would probably recommend overriding the version of Python for CMake and set it to 2.x instead.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiago](https://answers.ros.org/users/55516/hiago/) on 2020-06-05**:
It worked, it took me a while to uninstall, but it resolved, I was using 2 different tutorials, one using the version of python2 that ros uses and the other python3. I followed the own ros and it worked, thanks! :D